# How to get returned value using ArgumentCaptor in Unit Test?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, mockito

I use `ArgumentCaptor` in my unit tests in order to get the values passed to the method. However, for the following method, I need to grab the `updated` value that is not passed to method directly. So, how can I get `updated` parameter's value properly?

```
public CommandDTO update(UUID uuid, ItemPriceRequest itemPriceRequest) {

    // ...

    final ItemPrice updated = itemRepo.save(itemPriceRequest);
    return CommandDTO.builder().uuid(updated.getUuid()).build();
}
```

Comment: It is returned from `itemRepo`. Is `itemRepo` mock?

Comment: Yes, mock......

Comment: Then you know its value because you control what is returned from  `itemRepo.save(itemPriceRequest)`

Comment: Actually there is a private method, but I think I follow another approach. With the help of you, I find a solution, many thanks an regards.